# cursor.getCount() returning wrong count using rawQuery

Tags: java, sqlite, cursor

I have used rawQuery to fetch records from DB table. I have checked the query from log and it is executing perfectly in SQLite. But the cursor.getCount is returning wrong row count and cursor containing wrong resultset. I have used the following code:

```
Cursor productCursor = dataHelper.rawQuery(query_str, null);
int list_count = productCursor.getCount();
Log.d("list_count", ""+list_count);
productCursor.moveToFirst();
while(productCursor.isAfterLast() == false) {
    ......
}
```

There are actually 4 records but the cursor contains only 3 records. Tested in SQLite and got the correct resultset.
It would be helpful if anyone can point out my fault.

Comment: what do you mean by returning wrong count ?

Comment: what is your query_str? Did you try to run the same query in db?

Comment: Yes, i have run that query taken from log to the DB and the resultset contains 4 records. But the cursor contains only 3 records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this..

```
productCursor.moveToFirst();

do {
  // your code..

} while (productCursor.moveToNext());
```

Comment: could you explain the difference please?